# An infinite series expansion of $(1 + x)^n$ for all $n \in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

I came across the following binomial identity which I had never previously encountered.

$$(1+x)^n = \left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^{-n} = \left[\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) \right]^{-n} =  2^n\left(1 + \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{-n}$$

which, given the negative exponent, can be expanded as
$$ 2^n\left(1 - n\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2!}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2 + \dots \right) = 2^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(-n)_k}{k!}\left(\frac{(1-x)}{(1+x)}\right)^k $$

I'm aware of the binomial series for fractional and negative exponents. But typically a binomial series for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is described as, sort of, "collapsing" into the standard (finite) binomial formula, (since eventually terms have an $n - n$ factor and thus go to $0$). This lead me, perhaps naively, to believe there was no way of writing $(1 +x)^n$ as an infinite series when $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Restrictions on $x$ and convergence notwithstanding, does this look correct? If so, is this an identity of any significant utility or just a curiosity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will converge where
$|\frac{1-x}{1+x}| < 1$,
which holds for
all $x > 0$.

This is similar to the combining of
$\ln(1-x)
=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-...$
with
$\ln(1+x)
=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...$
to get
$\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})
=2(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+...)
$.

From this,
if
$y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$
then
$x=\frac{y-1}{y+1}
$
and given a positive $y$,
the series
$\ln(y)
=\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})
=2(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+...)
$
will converge.